# Output of Format from a string

Tags: excel, vba

Last night I ran into something that drove me nuts for a good ten, fifteen minutes before I figured it out. But I don't understand *why* it is this way, so I'm hoping someone here can elucidate.

From the Immediate window in the VBA IDE:

```
?Format(0.5, "HH:MM AM/PM")
12:00 PM
?Format("0.5", "HH:MM AM/PM")
12:05 AM
?Format(CDbl("0.5"), "HH:MM AM/PM")
12:00 PM
```

From [this page](http://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-using-dates-times-excel/#How-Excel-Stores-Times) I see that 0.5 should correspond to 12:00 PM, since one hour is 0.04166... (`(12 * (1/24) = 0.5)`). And as you can see, it does if I pass a number to `Format()` but not if I pass the same number as a string.

Per the info from the same page, 1 minute is 0.00069444... (`(1/(24*60))`), meaning 12:05 AM should be stored in Excel as 0.003472222 (`(0 * (1/24)) + (5 * (1/(24*60)))`). And, in fact:

```
?Format(0.003472222, "HH:MM AM/PM")
12:05 AM
```

Some more oddities I don't understand:

```
?Format(2.5, "HH:MM AM/PM")
12:00 PM
?Format("2.5", "HH:MM AM/PM")
02:05 AM
```

But...

```
?Format(2.523, "HH:MM AM/PM")
12:33 PM
?Format("2.523", "HH:MM AM/PM")
12:33 PM
```

Everything I can find in documentation says that "Times are stored as part of a real number. Values to the right of the decimal represent the time. For example, midday (12:00 P.M.) is represented by 0.5." (From Excel 2010's built-in VBE Glossary) So `2.5` should result in a time of 12:00 PM since the part to the right of the decimal is `0.5` and `2.523` should result in 12:33 PM since `0.523` = `(12 * (1/24)) + (33 * (1/(24*60)))`. But VBA only returns the correct result for one of those.

So can anyone explain *why* VBA exhibits what appears to be inconsistent behavior? Or is there some wrinkle I'm missing?

This was tested in Excel 2010 and 2013.

Comment: And this is why explicit types are important and letting VBA do implicit conversions for you, makes the language a headscratcher for so many people. Nice post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You expect `Format` to convert 0.5 to a double, but it doesn't. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198964.aspx, the String to Date implicit let conversion goes

- If it's a date/time, time, or date (in that order), convert it to a date.
- If it's in the range of a Double, convert it to a double then to a date.
- If neither of those, return an error.

Since it's not converting to a double, it must be converting on the first bullet. And it is. It's assuming "0.5" is a time. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528865.aspx, a decimal point is a valid time separator.

```
time-separator = *WSC (":" / ".") *WSC
```

Comment: Excellent links that perfectly explained the behavior I was seeing, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that you're asking VBA to format a `Double` and a `String`. You're expecting VBA to interpret the string value the same way as the double value.

If you have a string that represents midnight, it can be `12:00 AM` or `00:00` (in 24 hour format). VBA is interpreting the separator as either `:` or `.` in the same manner. So for a `String` formatted to represent five minutes after midnight, you can write `12:05 AM`, `00.05`, `0.5`, `0:05`, or `0:5`. Also look at the function `CDATE`.

All of the strings, when converted to `Double` give the same result:

```
?Cdbl(CDate("00.05"))
 3.472222222222222E-02
```